# Master master relationship getting "too many connections" error after extended outage

Tags: mariadb, master-master-replication

I have a master master database setup with an onprem and cloud hosted MariaDB server.  I can stop one database or the other for testing purposes and start it back up and everything seems fine.  The server that remains up will continue to serve connections when the other is down.  However, we had an extended power outage recently causing the connection between the two to break for around two hours.  After around an hour our cloud hosted server started throwing "too many connection" errors.  Is it possible that the cloud server kept trying to connect to the onprem master/slave and it resulted in hitting a limit on the number of connections?

All the retry and timeout values are default.  When the connection was back up, restarting the service in the cloud resulted in the sync catching up and everything working.  However, I'm looking for a way to keep my cloud hosted server serving connections even if the onpremise server is down for an extended period.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to stall the thundering herd before it gets to the database.
I recommend

- Change the number of allowed connections from the outside to the clients (Apache/Tomcat? and PHP/Java?) to be limited to less than MariaDB's `max_connections`/2.
- Catch the too-many-user case in the client code to say something like "the server is temporarily down".

Then, when the database comes back up, it will not be suddenly swamped.  Furthermore, MariaDB may actually work through the backlog faster than if it had hundreds of requests stumbling over each other.

(The problem you encountered can happen with a single DB server when `max_connections` is hit.)